# Simplifying $S=\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}-...+(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}$

Tags: combinatorics

Assume $n$ and $r$ are nonnegative integers where $$0\le r\le n$$How can one simplify $$S=\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}-...+(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}$$
?

I think that this combinatorial expression should be either solved using a combinatorial way but I don't know how. Probably It's also useful one tries to represent somehow using binomial representation of $(a+b)^n$.  I appreciate any idea given!

Comment: Expand $(1+(-1))^n$ using the binomial theorem.

Comment: @md2perpe how does that simplify things when $r \neq n$?

Comment: Oh, I missed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coefficient of $x^r$ in

$$(1-x)^n (1 + x + x^2 + ...) = (1-x)^{n-1}$$

So for $r \lt n$ it is $$(-1)^r\binom{n-1}{r}$$

Answer (score 4):

If you have no better idea, just work out the first terms and see what happens. So your first terms are:

$S_0=1$

$S_1=1-n$

$S_2=1-n+\cfrac {n(n-1)}2=\cfrac {n^2-3n+2}2=\cfrac {(n-1)(n-2)}2$

$S_3=\cfrac {(n-1)(n-2)}2-\cfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6=-\cfrac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}6$

After which it is very clear what is happening and how this will go through easily by induction.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the remainder term of a truncated Taylor series**
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^r{n \choose k}x^k + \int_0^x \frac{f^{(r+1)}(t)}{r!}(x-t)^r\,dt$$
Rearrange to put the truncated series on the LHS:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^r{n \choose k}x^k &= (1+x)^n - \int_0^x \frac{f^{(r+1)}(t)}{r!}(x-t)^r\,dt 
\\&= (1+x)^n - \frac{1}{r!}\frac{n!}{(n-r-1)!} \int_0^x (1+t)^{n-r-1}(x-t)^r\,dt
\end{align}$$
Substitute $x=-1$:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^r{n \choose k}(-1)^k &=  0-\frac{1}{r!}\frac{n!}{(n-r-1)!} (-1)^{r}\int_0^{-1} (1+t)^{n-1}\,dt\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{r!}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-r-1)!}[(1+t)^n]_0^{-1}
\\&=\frac{(-1)^{r}}{r!}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-r-1)!}
\\&=(-1)^r{n-1\choose r}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Just to present an alternative way to derive the result already 
provided in the answer by *Aryabhata*
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(r) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,r} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,r} {\left( \matrix{
  k - n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  = \quad \quad \quad (1)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,r} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  r - k \cr 
  r - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k - n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  = \quad \quad \quad (2)  \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{
  r - n \cr 
  r \cr}  \right) = \quad \quad \quad (3)  \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,r} \left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  r \cr}  \right)\quad \quad \quad (4) \cr} 
$$
where the following identities have been applied
  (1)  "Trinomial Revision";
  (2)  bounds on $k$ replaced by the 1st binomial;
  (3)  "Double convolution";
  (4)  "Trinomial Revision".